# javascript - Stop download the site when password is false

Tags: javascript, html, verify

I'm writing a simple Code Verify 
So can I forcing the site to stop downloaded when the code is false with javascript?

My example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <div class='content'></div>
    
  </body>
  
  
</html>
```

Comment: the simple HTML & want to restrict download! what do u want to ask?

Comment: What do you mean "Stop Download"? Stop rendering the web page or stop downloading something?

Comment: your code has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do window.stop(); for most browsers besides Internet Explorer. For IE, I had to use document.execCommand('Stop');